# Relating generating sets of modules over quotient ring to modules over original ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals

I am having trouble with the following exercise.

Let $R = F[x]$, where F is some field. Let $I = (x^2)$, and let M be an R/I-module (induced action, so assuming $IM = 0$). Then I want to show that the following statements are equivalent:

i) M is finitely generated as an R-module
ii) M is finitely generated as an R/I-module
iii) M is finite-dimensional as a vector space over F.

i) implies ii): since a generating set for M as an R-module gives a generating set for M as an R/I-module.

ii) implies iii): Can I just expand a generating set $\{a_1, a_2, \dots , a_n\}$ for M as an R/I-module to a generating set $\{a_1, a_2, \dots , a_n, xa_1, xa_2, \dots , xa_n\}$ as an F-module?

iii) implies i) This one should be obvious, as we can use the generating set for M as an R-module for M as an R-module.

My question is whether my arguments above are correct. Is there a better way to see things? Maybe from a general point of view? Are there any rings which are particularly nice in this regard? (I am aware of the existence of the Nakayama Lemma, and R/I is a local ring, so I might be able to apply it somehow)

Comment: There must be an error in your hypotheses: an $R$-modules has no reason to be an $R/I$-module.

Comment: The question is edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea for i$\Rightarrow$ii will work.

ii$\Rightarrow$iii is not so generic and depends on $I$. We know that $R/I$ itself has a basis $\{1,x\}$ over $F$ hence is a finite-dimensional $F$-vector space. A finitely generated $R/I$ module $M$ is a quotient of the free $R/I$ module on some finite generating set, and since this free module is essentially a finite direct sum of copies of $R/I$ it is finite-dimensional, hence so is $M$.

Your idea given in the post will also work if you want to work it out. This may be a good exercise.

Comment: So is my approach to ii) implies iii) correct, just not very general, and that's why you are describing a more general approach? Or is there a flaw in the argument?

Comment: @improve there's nothing wrong with your argument. Mine may seem more general, but it's actually just less elementary and more readily seen to generalize to any finite dimensional algebra. Yours also generalizes to arbitrary finite dimensional algebras without too much trouble.